# Sorting on list using comparator is not working

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I want to sort list of product data on the basis of axis type count.I am not able to find the issue in below code . How can i sort this result?

```
private void sortResults(List<ProductData> results) {
        Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<ProductData>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ProductData product1, ProductData product2) {
                return product1.getAxisTypeCount().compareTo(product2.getAxisTypeCount());
            }
        });}


ProductSearchPageData<SearchStateData, ProductData> searchPageData = null;
            searchPageData = encodeSearchPageData(productSearchFacade.textSearch(searchState, pageableData));
sortResults(searchPageData.getResults());
```

The expected result: `Makeup 37 , Watches 7 , jewelry 6 , skincare 6, Fragrance 4`

The actual result:  `Makeup 37 , Fragrance 4 , jewelry 6 , skincare 6,Watches 7`

Comment: what does `getAxisTypeCount()` return?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've posted. I think we need more information and context.

Comment: Can you show us the source to ProductData?

Comment: Please mention the code inside getAxisTypeCount() method !

Comment: As previously told, code seems ok. Add more information.

Comment: from your code the order completely depends on the 'getAxisTypeCount()' method of class 'ProductData' you need to look throught that code or please share the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sortResults(List<ProductData> results) {
    Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<ProductData>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ProductData product1, ProductData product2) {
            return product1.getAxisTypeCount().compareTo(product2.getAxisTypeCount());
        }
    });}
```

product1 would take second value from the list, whereas product2 will take first value from the list.
For instance:

Your list is `[Watches , jewelry, Fragrance, .........]`
On calling compare function `product1 = jewelry` and  `product2 = Watches`

I am assuming getAxisTypeCount() is giving integer value, if your object is "Makeup   37", getAxisTypeCount() would return 37

This line =>

```
return product1.getAxisTypeCount().compareTo(product2.getAxisTypeCount());
```

would result:

```
Fragrance   4
jewelry   6
skincare   6
Watches   7
Makeup   37
```

not as you mentioned in the actual result `Makeup 37 , Fragrance 4 , jewelry 6 , skincare 6, Watches 7`

If you want your compare method should result output as you mentioned in expected result: `Makeup 37 , Watches 7 , jewelry 6 , skincare 6, Fragrance 4`

This line `return product2.getAxisTypeCount().compareTo(product1.getAxisTypeCount())` will solve you problem.

```
private void sortResults(List<ProductData> results) {
    Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<ProductData>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ProductData product1, ProductData product2) {
            return product2.getAxisTypeCount().compareTo(product1.getAxisTypeCount());
        }
    });}
```

Comment: If you compare the actual output to your theory you see this cannot be the (only) problem.